# Слово "прошерстив" в журнальной статье

Tags: лексика

"Прошерстив все словари (магазины), она нашла лишь..."
Чем заменить  разг.-сниж. слово "прошерстив"? *Тщательно обыскав, обследовав, осмотрев, изучив*? Но все как-то не так.

Comment: От слова "шерсть", я думаю.  Как бы проведя рукой по шкуре животного с целью проверить состояние подшёрстка или кожи или посмотреть как мех на место уложится.

Answer (score 4):

*Проштудировав все словари*... *Тщательно изучив ассортимент всех магазинов*...

Comment: Спасибо! В моем случае "проштудировав" неуместно, но для словаря, пожалуй, этот вариант действительно наилучший. Пока что остановилась на "Пройдясь широким фронтом". Можно еще "Изучив вдоль и поперек". Но "изучив" все-таки несколько не подходит мне. Легло бы "облазив", да стилистика не та.

Comment: Слово "штудировать" имеет иной смысл, чем поиск чего-то в словаре: "штудируют" источник (учебник, конспект, инструкцию) с целью тщательно выучить его содержимое. В словаре же находят нужное по алфавитному указателю.

Comment: Если бы некто изучал значение заимствованных слов по "Словарю иностранных слов", то тогда, вероятно, можно было бы сказать, что он штудирует "Словарь иностранных слов"?

Answer (score 2):

Перебрав все словари (пелелистав журналы), обойдя все магазины...

**P.S.** ... и не пропустив ни одного (попавшегося, известного мне) интернет-магазина

Comment: Спасибо! А если это интернет-магазины?

Comment: Добавил в конце.

Answer (score 2):

Проверив - общее значение.

Просмотрев, пересмотрев - более узкое значение